# Matlab's 'FaceColor' ignoring inputs and choosing arbitrary colors

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, bar-chart

```
fig = figure('Color','w');
bar(MomVsMarket.Date, [MomVsMarket.MomHold4Weeks ...
    MomVsMarket.MomHold12Weeks  MomVsMarket.MomHold24Weeks],'grouped');
ylabel('Profitability in %');
xlabel('Time');
title('Profitability over Time');
ax = get(gca);
%set the first bar chart style
set(bar,'FaceColor', 'b' ,'BarWidth',2);
%set the second bar chart style
set(bar,'FaceColor','r','BarWidth',2);
%set the third bar chart style
set(bar,'FaceColor','y','BarWidth',2);
```

Produces my bar chart overlay **without the specified colors 'b', 'r' and 'y'**. Where is the error?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the return values of `bar` to get handles to the separate bar plots:

```
function q41648723
%% Generate some data:
d1 = datetime(2006,1,1,0,0,0);
d2 = datetime(2016,7,1,0,0,0);
date = d1:caldays(10):d2;
data = 5*randn(numel(date),3);

MomVsMarket = struct('Date',date,...
                     'MomHold4Weeks', data(:,1),...
                     'MomHold12Weeks',data(:,2),...
                     'MomHold24Weeks',data(:,3));
clear d1 d2 date data;
%% Plot:
figure('Color','w');
hB = bar(MomVsMarket.Date, [MomVsMarket.MomHold4Weeks,...
                            MomVsMarket.MomHold12Weeks,...
                            MomVsMarket.MomHold24Weeks],'grouped');
ylabel('Profitability in %');
xlabel('Time');
title('Profitability over Time');
%set the first bar chart style
set(hB(1),'FaceColor', 'b' ,'BarWidth',2);
%set the second bar chart style
set(hB(2),'FaceColor','r','BarWidth',2);
%set the third bar chart style
set(hB(3),'FaceColor','y','BarWidth',2);
```

Notice how I use `hB` in the code above. The above results in (MATLAB R2016b):

[image: What the OP wanted, I think...]

#### P.S.

Next time, please provide runnable code samples in your question (see: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). I could have given you an answer much sooner if I didn't have to come up with some test data on my own.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, @Dev-iL! Ok, understood for "Minimal, Complete & Verifiable", will do so next time